# Django. Detail.html page returns all posts from list.html on a single page

Tags: python, django, templates, django-views, get

I'm trying to create a blog with a title and description form and a photo created inline in the admin admin StackedInline.
So far, everything has worked, including the list.html page with the list of posts, but the detail.html page returns all posts on a single page. How to solve it? the page includes comment, I didn't find anything similar on the internet.
I would like the detail.html page to return only to the posts that belong to the main title in list.html

```
Models.py 




from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from taggit.managers import TaggableManager
from django.utils.html import mark_safe


class PublishedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status='published')

class Post(models.Model):    
    STATUS = (
    (0,"Draft"),
    (1,"Publish")
)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date='publish')
    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    description = models.TextField()    
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='uploads/')
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    published = PublishedManager() # Our custom manager. 
    #tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    
    
    def img_preview(self): #new
        return mark_safe(f'<img src = "{self.image.url}" width = "300"/>') 
   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    
    

class Travel(models.Model):
    travel = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="travel-post")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to ='uploads/')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects = models.Manager() # The default manager.
    
    
class Comment(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        ('Lido', 'Lido'),
        ('Não Lido', 'Não Lido'),
    )
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='comments')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    email = models.EmailField()
    body = models.TextField(max_length=800)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(choices=STATUS, max_length=10, default="Não Lido")


admin.py



from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Travel, Post, Comment


class TravelInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Travel
    extra = 0    
    list_display = ('title', 'user')
    list_filter = ( 'created', 'user')
    search_fields = ('title', 'description')   
    date_hierarchy = 'created'
    
    
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TravelInline]
    list_display = ['title', 'user', 'status']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}    


@admin.register(Comment)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email', 'post', 'created', 'status')
    list_filter = ('status', 'created', 'updated')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')


views.py



from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Travel, Post, Comment
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.db.models import Count
from .forms import EmailPostForm, CommentForm

# Create your views here.

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()   
    post_latest = Post.objects.order_by('id')[:3]     
    return render(request, 'travel/post/list.html', {
                                                'posts': posts,
                                                'post_latest': post_latest,
                                                }) 
    
def post_detail(request, id, slug):
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=id)
    travel = Travel.objects.all()      
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(post_id=id, status='Lido')
    total = 0    
        
    for i in comments:
        total = total + 1       
       
    context = {
        'post': post,
        'comments': comments,
        'travel': travel,
        'total': total,
        }    
    return render(request, 'travel/post/post_detail.html', context)


list.html



{% extends "travel/base.html" %}

{% block title %}Travel{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% for p in posts %}

          <h2 class="mb-0 text-capitalize"><b>{{ p.title }}</b></h2>        
          <div class="mb-1 text-muted"><h6>Published {{ p.publish }} by  {{ p.user }}</h6></div>
          <p class="card-text">{{ p.description|truncatewords:20|linebreaks }}</p>        
          <a href="/post/{{p.id}}/{{p.slug}}"
          class="stretched-link text-primary"><h5>Continue reading</h5></a>

{% if p.image %}
          <div class="col-auto d-none d-lg-block py-5">       
              <figure class="image">
                  <img src="{{ p.image.url }}" class="img-fluid" width="400" height="200">
              </figure>
          </div>
          {% endif %}<br>      

  {% endfor %}
   {% endblock %}


detail.html



{% extends "travel/base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ post.title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

  {% if post.image %}
  <div class="p-4 p-md-2 mb-4 rounded text-bg-dark"><img class="img-fluid" src="{{ post.image.url }}">
  {% endif %}

  <div class="col-md-6 py-3">
      <h1 class="display-4 fst-italic text-capitalize">{{ post.title }}</h1>
      <p class="lead my-3">{{ post.description }}.</p>      
  </div>
  

  <p class="date">
    Published {{post.publish }} by {{ post.User }}
  </p>
   {% for t in travel %}
<div class="position-relative overflow-hidden text-center bg-light">
    <div class="p-lg-5 mx-auto">
      <h1 class="display-4 fw-normal text-capitalize">{{ t.title }}</h1>
      <p class="lead fw-normal">{{ t.description|linebreaks }}</p>      
    </div>  
  
    {% if t.image %}
  <div class="p-4 p-md-2 mb-4" ><img class="img-fluid" src="{{ t.image.url }}" width="600"></div>
    {% endif %}
    
    {% endfor %}
  {% for comment in comments %}     

      <div class="card border-secondary mb-3" style="max-width: 40rem; justify-content-evenly d-flex flex-column position-static">
        <div class="card-header">Comment {{ forloop.counter }} by <span class="text-danger"> {{ comment.name }} </span> 
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          {{ comment.created }}
          <p class="card-text">{{ comment.body|linebreaks }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  {% empty %}
    <p>There are no comments yet.</p>   
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

I believe the error is
travel = Travel.objects.all()   in views.py
how do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this issue changing;

```
travel = Travel.objects.all()
```

for

```
travel = Travel.objects.all().filter(pk=id)
```